# What could be the possible reasons of remote linux host shows terminal prompt with around 15 seconds delay

Tags: linux, ssh, sshd, amazon-ec2, amazon-linux

When I try to `ssh` in to a linux host, its terminal prompt shows around 15 seconds later after entering the ssh command on my local computer. The subsequent connections take 2-3 seconds. However, waiting for sometime, after disconnecting from the remote host and reconnecting with `ssh`, it takes the same time as for the first time.

- The OS is Amazon Linux 2.
- The CPU and network graph shows no unusual before and after.
- `UseDNS` is commented out in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`.

What are the possible places I should take a look.

Comment: Any special MOTD, like running a script that times out?

Comment: Wild guess: There might be a DNS timeout somewhere, if the login script tries to fetch the host name of the connecting IP.

Comment: What's the network path between your computer and this EC2 instance in AWS?  Are you in an office that has a site-to-site VPN into AWS, and the VPN isn't kept running all the time, but instead connected and disconnected on demand?  Or perhaps your SSH is going through AWS System Manager (SSM) as a tunnel to the EC2 instance?  SSM sessions can involve some setup time.  Or is your home directory auto-mounted on the EC2 instance when you log in?

Answer (score 0):

Since you said "Amazon Linux 2", is this a cloud host?

If so, it might be that it simply takes that much time to figure out exactly where in the cloud your host is currently located and to create an appropriate NAT mappings to route your SSH connection there. But if there is already an existing connection, then the mappings are already in effect and your second and subsequent connections will be established quicker.

If you don't have anything in particular running in the cloud host, the cloud provider might even automatically suspend the host when it is detected to be completely idle with no network connections, to save power. Or they might migrate the virtual host to a different hardware unit in their datacenter to optimize their loads, and the first incoming SSH connection just triggers a re-optimization in terms of CPU resources vs. network connectivity, possibly causing your virtual machine to migrate to a different hardware unit.

Basically, this is a question you should ask your hosting provider.

Answer (score 0):

Its not clear from your desciption where the delay is occurring. Consider the steps involved after you hit 'enter' on the command line.

1. Your computer parses its ssh config. Since you're asking the question this is unlikely to be a significant overhead, but even very complx configs are usually processed quickly
2. You computer issues a DNS request to the (first) ssh endpoint and needs to wait for a reply. This will timeout around 30 seconds if there is no reply. Note that there can be multiple hops depending on how the access has been provisioned.
3. Your computer starts a TCP handshake to the endpoint. As telcoM says, this may take some time if there is some clever routing and/or firewalling happenning. Its not unusual to throttle connections to mitigate DOS.
4. The server presents its public key which is then validated by your machine.
5. The server starts executing a shell, running through all the startup files. That means ready a lot of files which are not necessarily in the cache. This might include displaying a banner message, configuring the PATH and prompt.
6. (optional) if this is a jump host, then the server becomes a client for the next hop, and runs through steps 2-5
7. You get a prompt from the remote system

ssh will multiplex connections, so when you make a second connection, you are starting at step 5.

Using `ssh -v` (or better `ssh -vvv`) will give you some insights into the time it takesfor these steps.

Answer (score 0):

There are so many potential reasons that nobody could list them *all*, and trying random ideas that come to mind can take forever.

(I've seen slowdowns due to calls to a misconfigured LDAP that would be slow to respond, lacking proper indexing. I've seen slowdowns due to a performance bug in the kernel on a very busy VM host. It can be very tricky to track down such problems.)

Instead, I suggest you try to find out where time is spent when logging in.

I'd start with something like this:

`script -fc 'ssh -v server' -t /dev/null`

This will cause `ssh` to log many of its steps, and `script` will emit (on stderr) how much time ran between lines.

Looking at a simpler example:

```
script -fc 'echo a; sleep 1; echo b; sleep 1; echo c' -t /dev/null 
Script started, output log file is '/dev/null', timing file is '/dev/stderr'.
a
0.000733 3
          b
1.000921 3
          c
1.001222 3
          Script done.
```

Here we can see that it took about 1 second between lines "a" and "b", and again between "b" and "c" (`script` emits timing info *after* the line).

`ssh -v` can be so verbose that you probably want to run the `script` command itself inside a script session. :)

This might give you some clues as to whether the slowdown happens somewhere between the client and the server, or chiefly on the server.

You can also try connecting from the server itself, thus removing latency between the client and the server.

If the slowdown happens mostly on the server, you want to look at logs for the ssh server and for PAM (e.g. `journalctl -u ssh -ef), and also keep an eye on top while connecting.